# Telegram bot replying in private but when used in a normal chat

Tags: python, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying out the bot API from telegram, and I'm using the wrapper `python-telegram-bot` for it. Currently my bot is able to behave as expected when initiating a conversation with the bot directly. However, when using the bot in a group or just mentioning the bot in a normal chat with another person the bot doesn't seem to see the message at all.

Using telegram botFather, I have `join to groups` enabled, I tried enabling and disabling `inline mode` (no effect on this issue).

The code that I have is like this: (Code is adapted from basic [wiki](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Your-first-Bot) examples)

```py
# Imports
from telegram import InlineQueryResultArticle, ParseMode, \
    InputTextMessageContent
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, InlineQueryHandler, Handler, ConversationHandler, CallbackQueryHandler
from telegram.utils.helpers import escape_markdown
from telegram import MessageEntity, ChatAction

# functions
def start(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /start is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Let\'s start')

def help(update, context):
    """Send a message when the command /help is issued."""
    update.message.reply_text('Help!')

def error(update, context):
    """Log Errors caused by Updates."""
    logger.warning('Update "%s" caused error "%s"', update, context.error)

def process(update, context):
    print(f'got this ==> {update.message.text}')
    query = update.message.text
    output = "Some output here"
    update.message.reply_text(output)

def run_bot():
    # Create the Updater and pass it your bot's token.
    # Make sure to set use_context=True to use the new context based callbacks
    # Post version 12 this will no longer be necessary
    updater = Updater("TOKEN_HERE", use_context=True)

    # Get the dispatcher to register handlers
    dp = updater.dispatcher

    # on different commands - answer in Telegram
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("help", help))

    # on noncommand i.e message 
    dp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text & (~Filters.command), process))


    # log all errors
    dp.add_error_handler(error)

    # Start the Bot
    updater.start_polling()

    # Block until the user presses Ctrl-C or the process receives SIGINT,
    # SIGTERM or SIGABRT. This should be used most of the time, since
    # start_polling() is non-blocking and will stop the bot gracefully.
    updater.idle()
```

and then I just run `run_bot()`.

Answer (score 0):

Talk to BotFather and **disable the privacy mode** of your bot.

Why? Well, the [official page](https://core.telegram.org/bots#privacy-mode) can answer that:

> A bot running in privacy mode will not receive all messages that people send to the group. Instead, it will only receive:
>
> - Messages that start with a slash ‘/’ (see Commands above)
> - Replies to the bot's own messages
> - Service messages (people added or removed from the group, etc.)
> - Messages from channels where it's a member

Also I suggest you to check the [FAQ of this topic](https://core.telegram.org/bots/faq#what-messages-will-my-bot-get).

Remember to filter the messages you want to answer otherwise you may end up spamming the group.

Comment: Actually I don't want the bot to listen to all messages and filter the messages, I want the bot to answer only when mentioned, this should be doable without changing privacy settings. However, this is not happening here!

Comment: Can you give an example of what are you expecting to receive? To see if it fits what the point 3 of the FAQ says.